# Startup applications folder location

Tags: launcher, backup, .desktop, startup-applications

Where is location of startup application folder ? If there is one of course . Maybe there is a config file , like terminal history (.bash_history) . The reason for the question is to get a backup for fresh installations .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The directory for (local) Startup Applications is `~/.config/autostart`.  Startup Applications creates `.desktop` files in the directory, which are automatically launched on ***log in***.

`.desktop` files there *can* include the line:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

but not necessarily. If they are *disabled* by Startup Applications, the file will include the line:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

#### Local versus global `.desktop` files

As mentioned by Chai T.Rex, startup launchers in `/etc/xdg/autostart` work for all users (also on log in).

However:

If launchers are set in `/etc/xdg/autostart`, but *disabled* locally, the local one in `~/.config/autostart` overrules the one in `/etc/xdg/autostart`.